# Reloading an iframe in GWT

Tags: gwt, iframe, refresh, frame, reload

I am currently working on a GWT project where I am displaying an HTML file within an iframe in my application.  This HTML file is actually being written to as it is getting displayed, and I am hoping to be able to reload the frame so that the changes made to the HTML file are reflected on screen.  I am able to do this two different ways that both work when running in development mode, however neither seem to work when the project is deployed.

The first method I tried was setting the frame's URL to itself:

```
frame.setUrl(frame.getUrl());
```

The second method I tried using JSNI:

```
public native void refresh() /*-{
  if($doc.getElementById('__reportFrame') != null) {
    $doc.getElementById('__reportFrame').src =
       $doc.getElementById('__reportFrame').src;
  }
}-*/;
```

When deployed, the frame gets displayed in a Window, and when the file is finished being written to, a call to either of these refresh methods is made, and the frame refreshes to contain the finished HTML file.  When I am deployed, the call to refresh does not reload the contents of the frame, however if I bring up the frame's context menu (in Firefox), then go into 'This Frame', and click Reload, it successfully reloads the frame to contain the finished HTML file.  I have tested this on multiple versions of Firefox without any luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Why would the behavior be different from one mode to the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, google is really fast with his search^^

> You can use some JSNI to do this. Create a method such as
>
> protected native void reloadIFrame(Element iframeEl) /*-{ 
>   iframeEl.contentWindow.location.reload(true);  }-*/;
>
> ```
>  Then call it with your iFrame element
> ```

so your question you posted twice was already answerd here 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/64aa7712890652d3

Answer (score 0):

We had a requirement where one GWT application(parent) had another GWT application(child) loaded in an iframe. The child application had to refresh the iframe after it performs certain DB operations. We used JSNI to accomplish the same.

```
private native void refreshChild(String url)/*-{
 $wnd.location.href=url; 
}-*/
```

In case, if the child frame needs to be redirected to another webpage, the url can be modified accordingly. 
We did try to use the reload() method, but it did not help. 
The above piece of code, of course needs to be written in the child application.